# Custom directive not working within a custom component

Tags: angular

Angular v.8 framework.

I have a custom directive with the selector of 'search-country'. The directive itself is declared and  exported in my SharedModule.
Also I have a component with the selector 'country-phone-code-input'.
If I have this component in my app.component.html as:

```
<country-phone-code-input search-country></country-phone-code-input>
```

The directive works as it should do but... if I'm removing the selector from the component selector and adding it inside the component, onto an input control:

```
<input type="text" search-country />
```

or

```
<div search-country></div>
```

the directive stops working, not firing at all. I have console.log('test') within the directive's constructor, no messages at the JS console.

What is the issue?

Comment: The tags don't clarify if we are talking about angular or angularjs. Also a stackblitz would be great here.

Comment: I've removed the angularjs-directory tag

Comment: It is not an answer, but a comment. I requested some more input. Your last comment-question is really misleading and doesn't mirror any of my intentions about your question. I consider this as rude. Now more questions about your issue: What means "stops working"? Is there any error? Which behavior doesn't occur? Are you sure it is the directive which is not working? I ask because the input is missing the `/` before the closing `>`

Comment: Provide all information about modules, components, imports / exports, etc. As much as you can. Nobody can provide you anything based on what you've told.

Answer (score 0):

This was the issue, the component and the directive to be included into the same module.

[image]